# SELECT from table name held in a string

Tags: mysql, sql, string

I need to select from a table, but I don't know its name up-front. So first I need to get its name:

```
select @table_name =
    convert(varchar(100), (select TOP 1 AnalysisTargetSID 
                           from M68_DSResult..tAnalysisTarget))+ 
    '_c1_LOSS_StagingLocation'
```

This query gives me a string `- 1627_c1_LOSS_StagingLocation`

And then I want to select from that table:

```
select * from [- 1627_c1_LOSS_StagingLocation]
```

Comment: I don't quite get what you want to accomplish, are you saying you want to execute a query contained in a string? Can you give an example of what you want to accomplishing? What is the issue you have? What results you are getting and how they differ from what you want?

Comment: I want to select * from abcd_1627_c1_LOSS_StagingLocation_abcd basically

Comment: and part of table name abcd_1627_c1_LOSS_StagingLocation_abcd  I get from - select 
    convert(varchar(100), (select TOP 1 AnalysisTargetSID 
                           from M68_DSResult..tAnalysisTarget))+ 
    '_c1_LOSS_StagingLocation'      which is 1627_c1_LOSS_StagingLocation

Comment: Ah got it now, what Database Server are you using? MS SQL, MY SQL, ORACLE?

Comment: Server is mssql I am using SSMS (management Studio) Thanks

Comment: I will see if i can write down an example for you later, I usually work with Oracle. In MS SQL you have Dynamic SQL. You can create a store procedure and inside of it use the EXECUTE Command or sp_executesql statement. Those commands execute a string as sql  command. Here you can find a nice article comparing them http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/20815/Building-Dynamic-SQL-In-a-Stored-Procedure. Basically you would create a strinc containing your select and use those commands to execute them.

Comment: Yes, let me know if you can do in oracle,

Comment: Clarify that asker needs to write dynamic sql

Comment: Here there is another nice resource you can check out to understand better what you need to do: http://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/1160/execute-dynamic-sql-commands-in-sql-server/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just build that statement and pass it to `EXEC`:

```
EXEC('select * from [' + @table_name + ']')
```